# "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException" even when running in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

I'm getting the android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException error even when I'm running the code inside AsyncTask thread. This is basically just a chunk of code that should return me a value from a website.

```java
package com.jasperhonkasalo.merenpinnankorkeusvsa;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;




public class NewBackgroundTask {



    public static class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        String value = "presetvalue";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            class NamespaceResolver implements NamespaceContext {
                private Document document;

                public NamespaceResolver(Document doc) {
                    document = doc;
                }

                public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
                    if (prefix.equals("")) {
                        return document.lookupNamespaceURI(null);
                    } else {
                        return document.lookupNamespaceURI(prefix);
                    }
                }

                public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
                    return document.lookupPrefix(namespaceURI);
                }

                public Iterator<String> getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
                    return null;
                }
            }


            try {
                String url = "http://opendata.fmi.fi/wfs/fin?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&storedquery_id=fmi::observations::mareograph::timevaluepair&fmisid=134223&";

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                try (BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(url).openStream(), "UTF-8"))) {
                    String line;
                    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                }
                String xml = sb.toString();

                DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
                Document document = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

                XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

                xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceResolver(document));

                String time = xpath.evaluate("//wml2:MeasurementTimeseries[@gml:id='obs-obs-1-1-WATLEV']/wml2:point[last()]//wml2:time", document);
                value = xpath.evaluate("//wml2:MeasurementTimeseries[@gml:id='obs-obs-1-1-WATLEV']/wml2:point[last()]//wml2:value", document);
                System.out.format("time = %s; value = %s\n", time, value);
                return value;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("EXCEPTIONFAIL", e.toString());
                return "FAIL: " + e.toString();
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String feed) {
            // TODO: do something with the feed
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the value with:

```java
static String eeee = new NewBackgroundTask.BackgroundTask().value;
```

The value of "value"- variable is staying the same (presetvalue) and also giving me a android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException error. I'm really new to any java programming and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please edit your question and show how you are attempting to use this class. Also, please note that `AsyncTask` is no longer recommended. Please consider using other up-to-date background threading options. In your case, you could switch to using OkHttp, which not only has its own background threading option but is *much* more modern than your current HTTP solution. Also note that `http` is not supported by default on Android 8.0+ -- please try to switch to `https`.

Comment: What is `.value`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce `.value` is the value inside "BackgroundTask" class that i want to get.

Comment: @Zoe That's exactly what I did if you take a look at the answer to that question. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute the AsyncTask, you cannot simply access a static field of it and expect it to give you any result. You need to do something like that:

```
new BackgroundTask().execute();
```

Since this is an asynchronous call, it cannot return a result directly (that's what asynchronous means). Instead, you get the result in the `onPostExecute()` method, which is executed in the main thread.

If you are really completely new to Java programming, you should perhaps not start with asynchronous method calls. That's something, even experienced developers have sometimes problems with.

Comment: Oh right, thanks! How can I execute it in this context, I just can't figure it out?

Comment: I actually tried that `new BackgroundTask().execute();`, but it just gave me a "Incompatible types" error.

Comment: You probably tried `String eee = new BackgroundTask().execute();`, but as I said above, the execute() does not return a value (hence the error, because String and void are not compatible), instead the value of the background work is return in the `onPostExecute()` method. So you'll have to change your code accordingly.

Comment: Oh yeah that actually makes sense. Could you give me an example of how I could get the value from `onPostExecute()`?

Comment: You don't get the value _from_ `onPostExecute()`, onPostExecute() is called after the asynchronous task is finished. That can be 1 millisecond after you called execute(), or it could be 5 minutes after you called it. That's why it is called asynchronous -- the async task is running in parallel to your main application. The app does not wait for a result, after you called execute(), it immediately continues with the next line of code. So you have to handle the result _inside_ the onPostExecute() method.